# Symfony2 Ajax update value (Facebook "like" style button)

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to implement a like/follow type button, and my problem is that I want to update the "Followers" value without refreshing the whole page. But I don't reach the solution.

I have a page where all the posts are loaded dynamically like this:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
         {% for sueno in suenos %}
            {% if loop.index0 is even %}
                {{ render(controller('SuenoBundle:Default:suenoFrontend', { 'sueno': sueno } )) }}
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
       </div><!--/col-md-6-->
```

And the template for rendering every single post is this:

```
 <div id="{{ sueno.id }}">
  <h4 class="text-center nombre-usuario">{{ sueno.usuario.username }}</h4>   
      {% if sueno.necesitaAyuda == 1 %}
              <div>
                <p class="pull-right">
                <a href="" class="menu-arriba">Colaborar</a>
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/compartir.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Compartir" class="menu-arriba"/>
                <a id="{{ sueno.id }}" href="{{ path('seguir', { 'suenoid': sueno.id }) }}" class="seguir menu-arriba"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguidores.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguir" /></a> 
                </p>
            </div>     
      {% endif %}                    
      {% if sueno.rol == 'foto' %}
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal" data-image="{{ asset('upload/images/' ~ sueno.fotoLink) }}" onclick="verFoto(this.getAttribute('data-image'))"><img src="{{ asset('upload/images/' ~ sueno.fotoLink) }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image"></a>
      {% elseif sueno.rol == 'video' %}
              <div class="video-container"><iframe src="{{ sueno.linkVideo }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
      {% endif %}
              <h4 class="text-center titulo-sueno">{{ sueno.titulo }}</h4>
              <h4 class="text-center quepido-sueno">{{ sueno.quePido }}</h4>
              <p class="text-center texto-sueno info">{{ sueno.texto }}</p>   
              <br>
            <div>
                {% set size = sueno.usuariosColaboradores | length %}
                {% set size2 = sueno.usuariosSeguidores | length %}
                <p class="text-center opciones-sueno">
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/colab.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Colaboradores" /> {{ size }}
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/punto.png') }}" width="5" height="5" alt="punto" />
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguid.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguidores" /> {{ size2 }}
                </p>
            </div>
        <hr>
</div>
```

The size2 element in this line is the data value I want to change. When loading the post the first time i just need to obtain the data from the variable I obtained from the controller:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguid.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguidores" /> {{ size2 }}
```

When I click here, is when the action happens:

```
<a id="{{ sueno.id }}" href="{{ path('seguir', { 'suenoid': sueno.id }) }}" class="seguir menu-arriba"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/estructura/images/seguidores.png') }}" width="20" height="20" alt="Seguir" /></a>
```

This is the code I have for the action. I just add a follower to the post. but here iw where I don'n know how to continue. I want to get the number of followers(is not written but I know how to do ir in the controller), and return it and update the data in the html.

```
public function seguirAction($suenoid)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $usuario = $this->getUser();

    $sueno = $em->getRepository('SuenoBundle:Sueno')->findOneBy(array('id' => $suenoid));

    $usuario->getSuenosSigue()->add($sueno);  
    $em->persist($usuario);
    $em->flush();

    //How to continue?

}
```

Comment: I think you need to retrieve the new `size2` value from the controller, with the same way you pass variables to your templates. And then, when the ajax response returns, change the value. You can wrap `size2` inside a `<span id="whatever">` to easily change it's value.

Comment: Por cierto, ya que veo que eres paisano, te puedo dar alguna indicación en castellano (euskera no, que estoy oxidado xD)

Comment: De hecho nos conocemos! jaja. Voy a intentarlo y si no te importa te contacto por FB por si necesito una mano...